# Is the relation $P(n) \sim \frac{1}{2^n}$ already known?

Tags: prime-numbers, zeta-functions

Apologies in advance if there is a violation of rules/laws here, as I am not a mathematician.

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \frac{\pi^{n}}{\zeta(n)}P(n) \right)^{\frac{1}{n}} &= \frac{\pi}{2}
\\
\\
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \pi^{n}P(n) \right)^{\frac{1}{n}} &= \frac{\pi}{2}
\hspace{2cm}\lim_{n\to\infty} \zeta(n) = 1
\\
\\
\lim_{n\to\infty} \pi P(n)^{\frac{1}{n}} &= \frac{\pi}{2}
\\
\\
\lim_{n\to\infty} P(n)^{\frac{1}{n}} &= \frac{1}{2}
\\
\\
P(n) &\sim \frac{1}{2^n}
\end{align}
$$

Where $P(n)$ is the prime zeta function
$$P(n) = \sum_p \frac{1}{p^n}$$

Numerical calculations (from WolframAlpha) suggest this is true:

\begin{align*}
P(500) &\approx 3.054936363499604682051979393213617699789402740572326663... × 10^{-151} \\
2^{-500} &\approx 3.054936363499604682051979393213617699789402740572326663... × 10^{-151}\end{align*}

Comment: @user254665 The prime zeta function. Also edited above

Comment: Could you explain the last step, how you get from $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(n)^{\frac1n}=\frac12$ to $P(n)\sim(\frac12)^n$?

Comment: @bof Raising both sides to the power of $n$

Comment: I believe that $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{\frac1n}=1$ but I don't think it follows that $n\sim1^n$, so I have doubts about "raising both sides to the power of $n$".

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I just *had* to line up the last two lines :)

Comment: @pjs36 Not at all. Looks much better now, thank you.

Comment: Anyway, with that kind of numerical evidence, who needs a proof? :-)

Comment: $1/2^n$ dominates the other terms in the sum, so of course the sum is asymptotic to $1/2^n$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I see. That explains it! I just took a complicated route, that is all.

Comment: To continue Gerry's comment, the series for $P(n)$ is its own asymptotic series.

Answer (score 4):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.*

I suppose that you could be interested by [this paper](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1306/1306.0496.pdf) where the author proposes $$\frac 1{P(n)}=2^n-\big(\frac 43\big)^n+\big(\frac 89\big)^n-\big(\frac 45\big)^n-\big(\frac {16}{27}\big)^n-\big(\frac 47\big)^n+2\big(\frac {8}{15}\big)^n+\big(\frac {32}{81}\big)^n+\cdots$$

For $P(10)$, the expansion (truncated to the  terms given here) gives an error $\approx -6.35 \times 10^{-12}$ and $P(10)\approx 0.000993604$ is already very close to $2^{-10} \approx 0.000976563$.

More empirical : generating the exact values of $P(n)$ for $10\leq n \leq 100$ and performing a nonlinear regression, we can get $$P(n)\approx 0.500741^n$$ the standard error on the tuned parameter being $0.000021$.

Comment: Hello again, @Claude Leibovici. Are you able to help with: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4546174/322359?

Comment: @user3108815. I have been working this problem but ... no idea ! Sorry