# Partial Sum Formula for Generalized Harmonic Number Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, harmonic-numbers

Given $[n, m, a] \in \Bbb R$, what is the partial sum formula for:

$$\sum_{x=1}^m\frac{H_{n,2x-1}}{a^x} = ???$$

Where $H_{x,y}$ is the generalized harmonic number. For context, while working on the a proof involving the polygamma function, I came across:

$$\sum_{x=1}^m\frac{\psi^{(2x-2)}(n+1)-\psi^{(2x-2)}(1)}{a^x (2x-2)!} =\ ???$$

Thanks to [Wolfram Research's Functions Site](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/PolyGamma2/03/01/02/0002/) I deduced that:
$$\sum_{x=1}^m\frac{\psi^{(2x-2)}(n+1)-\psi^{(2x-2)}(1)}{a^x (2x-2)!} =\ \sum_{x=1}^m\frac{-[\zeta(2x-1)-H_{n,\ 2x-1}]-(-\zeta(2x-1))}{a^x}$$

Which of course is just:
$$\sum_{x=1}^m\frac{H_{n,\ 2x-1}}{a^x} =\ ???$$

EDIT: I'm getting very close to an answer for this! The depth of the problem is actually quite shocking, to me at least!

Comment: What have you tried so far? At which step of the process are you having trouble?

Comment: @lafinur Was editing previously, but detail has been added!